# How to configure Tomcat to Not use Database Connection Pooling

Tags: mysql, tomcat, jdbc

How can you configure Tomcat to **Not** use Database Connection Pooling ?

I want to do this because I have an application that makes very few calls to the mysql database, typically less than 10 in a 24 hour period and some calls fail on retrieving the connection. It appears that Mysql is sometimes giving up on the connection because it has been idle for so long without telling the database pooler.

Worth noting that I have another application that makes thousands of requests to the exact same database and this never fails, so I am convinced the issue is related to the rarity of calls to the database. Mysql is probably part of the problem but updating to Postgres would be a larger task than I want to commit to right now.

So I tried configuring context.xml to `testWhileIdle` but it is stil failing

```
<Context path="/store" privileged="true">
    <Resource name="jdbc/myapp" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              maxActive="100" maxIdle="100" maxWait="10000" testWhileIdle="true"
              username="usrnm" password="pwd" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myapp"/>

</Context>
```

So now I want to disable pooling so its get a new connection every time but I cant work out how to do it, Ive looked at

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#Plain_Ol%27_Java

but everything seems to be centered out database pooling.

**Attempted Solution**

So I tried out suggestion in answer and will see what happens over next few days

```
     <Context path="/store" privileged="true">
            <Resource name="jdbc/myapp" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                      maxActive="10" maxIdle="10" 
    testWhileIdle="true" validationQuery="select 1" validationQueryTimeout="5"
                      username="usrnm" password="pwd" 
driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" testOnBorrow="true"
                      url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myapp"/>

        </Context>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing should be preventing you from making your own connections and using them. But, I think you are missing configuration to make the connection validation work properly. When a connection is tested and found to be bad it should be replaced by a new one prior to the pool giving you the connection. I think you are missing validationQuery which would be utilized when testing the connection. Check out the docs at https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html and look at supplying the necessary values for the validation to work. Try testOnBorrow and validationQuery so that each time you go for a connection it will validation it prior to returning. Also, you appear to be setting up way too many connections based on your frequency of usage. Tuning that should help avoid keeping unnecessary connections open.

Comment: I don't want to bypass the tomcat db connection stuff I just want to configure it so it creates a new connection each time a request is made, not clear if this is possible but Ill try setting the validationQuery you might be right there.

Comment: @PaulTaylor I think the title threw me off, thought you were trying to not use the pooling.

Comment: Sorry I meant I didnt want tomcat to pool db connections, anyway I made described changes and it hasnt failed yet so fingers crossed.

Comment: iStill working. i think the key thing was what you said about needing a validationQuery, thanks